# Deserializing Avro json to AVRO class

Tags: java, json, avro

I have below `avro json` string, however while doing the deserialization to `MyClass.java` using the `ObjectMapper` I am not able to deserialize it and the Object is created with all `null` values. How do I deserialize below json string to an `AVRO` class?

```
a.b.c.MyClass: {

id: 1,
name : "Saurabh"

}
```

**MyClass.java (Generated AVRO class of type SpecificRecordBase)**

```
class MyClass 
{
int id;
String name;
}
```